# glob() to show files from folder based on user input

Tags: php, pdf, glob

I have a directory structure like this:

- Tools/folder-1/pdfs
- Tools/folder-2/pdfs
- Tools/folder-3/pdfs
- Tools/folder-4/pdfs

etc.

I want to show files from folder which will user enter into search field e.g he will enter folder-1.

Here is my code now it is showing files from only one folder which I assigned to $folder_name which changes I will need to make in this code to get the above mentioned result.:

```
if ($folder_name == $search_text) {

    echo "<button class=\"btn-primary\">Reports for <b> ' ".$search_text." ' 
    </b></button><br/>";
    echo '<ul class="results">
    <p class="result-bx-txt">Please click a link below to download the tool 
    report</p>';

    foreach (glob('Tools/*/*.pdf') as $filename) {

    echo "<li><a href=\"$filename\">";          
    echo basename($filename);
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<span class="file-size">';
    echo filesize($filename);
    echo 'kb</span>';
    echo "</li></p><br/>";    
    }

    echo '</ul>';

 } else {
    echo "<button class=\"btn-primary\">Reports for <b> ' ".$search_text." ' 
    </b></button><br/>";
    echo '<ul class="results">';
    echo '<li>No such file found!</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
 }

}
```

Comment: I'm missing your question here, please can you edit your post.

Comment: Thanks bkausbk  can you please let me know how can I pass $search_text variable into glob();?

Comment: Do you mean you want to search only that files that matches your search text? How about `glob("Tools/" . $search_text . "/*.pdf")`?